# Adding Time Buttons in JQuery Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I am trying to adapt the countdown timer from http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Simple-jQuery-Html5-Based-360-Degree-Countdown-Timer-countdown360.html to add buttons which determine the time to count down.

I am a little confused (no, really a lot confused) about 
a) how to link the buttons to the countdown display,
b) how to stop the display starting until I have clicked the desired button, and 
c) how to reset the process without reloading the page.

Currently it takes the initial seconds value of 10 (put there just to test to see what it is doing) but does not respond to the buttons.

Here is the html:

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/jquery.countdown360.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
   </head>

 <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="countdown"></div>



 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $("#countdown").countdown360({
     radius      : 50,
     seconds     : 10,
     fontColor   : '#FFFFFF',
     autostart   : false,
     onComplete  : function () {//will ring bell 
     }
       }).start()
 </script>          

 <script>           
 window.onload = init;

 function init(){
   document.getElementById('btnStart1').onclick = start1;
   document.getElementById('btnStart2').onclick = start2;
   document.getElementById('btnReset').onclick = cdreset;
   start.countdown360();
  }

 function start1(){ // starts 1 min countdown
   seconds = 60;
   countdown360();
  }

 function start2(){ // starts 2 min countdown
   seconds = 120;
   countdown360();
  }

 function reset() { // resets countdown
   seconds=0;
   //???
  }

</script>               


</div>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="countdown"></div>

<input type="button" value="1 min" id="btnStart1"/>
<input type="button" value="2 min" id="btnStart2"/>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Reset" id="btnReset"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be most welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer & Demo

So it turns out there isn't a legit way of doing this, truth be told there isn't a lot of documentation about the subject and the plugin itself doesn't provide such functionability, or at least not in a user friendly way.

But I went down to the guts of the code and **managed to make it work**.
Here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zncsd1d5/7/) where I demonstrate what I understood you wanted.

### HTML

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="set60">Set 60s</button>
<button id="set120">Set 120s</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

### JavaScript

```
start = document.querySelector("#start");
set60 = document.querySelector("#set60");
set120 = document.querySelector("#set120");
reset = document.querySelector("#reset");

div = $("#countdown");
pingSound = new Audio("http://www.sounddogs.com/previews/2220/mp3/402763_SOUNDDOGS__mu.mp3");
pingSound.preload = "auto"; //<- Optional but recommended

countdown = div.countdown360({
    radius: 50,
    seconds: 30,
    fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    autostart: false,
    onComplete: function () {
        pingSound.play();
    }
});

countdown.start(); //This right here is for showing the clock on load.
countdown.stop();

start.onclick = function () {
    startCountdown(countdown);
}
set60.onclick = function () {
    setSeconds(countdown, 60);
}
set120.onclick = function () {
    setSeconds(countdown, 120);
}
reset.onclick = function () {
    setSeconds(countdown, 0);
}

function startCountdown(countdown) {
    countdown.start();
}

function setSeconds(countdown, seconds) {
    countdown.stop();
    countdown.settings.seconds = seconds;
    countdown.start();
}
```

### Explanation

#### Variables

- **start, set60, set120, reset** : Link to their respective `button` elements.
- **div** : Link to the countdown `div` element.
- **pingSound** : `Audio` element that contains the "ping" sound.
- **countdown** : The countdown object itself, you *need* to declare it like this, passing the initial properties and saving it in a variable.

#### Functions

- **startCountdown(*countdown*)** : Takes any countdown object and start's it's execution, this will get the countdown running.
- **setSeconds(*countdown*,*seconds*)** : Takes any countdown object and set's it second (it can be used in mid-excecution). It works by first stopping the countdown, then updating the `Countdown.settings.seconds` property, which is the actual seconds the countdown will run.

#### Development

With those *variables & methods*, how I did it is pretty straight forward.

**If you want the clock hidden until you play it:**

We first create the countdown object and hide the div.

```
div = $("#countdown");
div.css( "display" , "none" );

countdown = div.countdown360({..});
```

**Why?** Well because of *how the plugin works*. As soon as you create the countdown your div is made bigger by the plugin, and you need to create the countdown there because that's the only way it works, so if you don't want a blank square of nothing (since we haven't started the countdown) you have to hide the div itself.

So, we add an `onclick` event to each button:

- for `start` -> `startCountdown(countdown) , div.css( "display" , "block" );` -> Starts the countdown and shows the div.
- for `set60` -> `setSeconds(countdown,60)` -> Sets the countdown to 60s.
- for `set120` -> `setSeconds(countdown,120)` -> Sets the countdown to 120s.
- for `set0` -> `setSeconds(countdown,0)` -> Sets the countdown to 0s.

And that's it, it took me a while to figure out, hopefully I didn't just bore you to death, and may I suggest getting a better plugin next time? Good luck :)

**If you want the clock displayed on load:**

Okey, so this is an update upon your request, if we part from my original code, to make the div appear on load is quite simple (JSFiddle & code here have been updated)

We first create the countdown object, then start it and inmeadiatly stop it (freezing it until you start it again).

```
countdown = div.countdown360({..});

countdown.start();
countdown.stop();
```

Now, we add the same `onclick` events to the buttons except for the start button, which will no longer have to display the div as block as it isn't hidden.

- for `start` -> `startCountdown(countdown)` -> Starts the countdown.
- (..)

**If you want to play a sound at the end of the countdown:**

For the ping sound to play in the end, you just need to create a new `Audio` object with the mp3/ogg src as a parameter:

```
pingSound = new Audio("http://www.sounddogs.com/previews/2220/mp3/402763_SOUNDDOGS__mu.mp3");
```

Then, preload the audio so it's ready to play (otherwise when you call play it will first have to load). This is optional but recommended.

```
pingSound.preload = "auto";
```

And then call the `Audio.play()` function in the countdown's `onComplete` event.

```
countdown = div.countdown360({
    (..)
    onComplete:function(){
        pingSound.play();
    }
});
```

That's it, happy coding :)

### Updates

- Updated code to display the clock on load (*1:43p.m 31/12/14*)
- Updated code to play sound in the end of countdown(*6:10p.m 02/01/14*)

Comment: WOW! Thank you for all this work -- that's amazing! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is there any way to display to clock before any buttons are pressed, rather than having it pop into being when "Start" is pressed? I experimented with <body onload> but haven't found a function that will initialize the image.

Comment: Oh, what? Yes man there is! I went through all that trouble just to hide it hahahahahaha, let me fix the code :) The clock will be displayed but not played until you say so :)

Comment: One more small problem: I can't work out (being unfamiliar with jQuery) how to play the sound when the timer hits 0. I have a function, but I am not sure how to call it:                          var pingSound = new Audio(); 
  pingSound.src = "ping.mp3"; 
  
  function timerSound()
  { 
  pingSound.play(); // Play timeout sound now 
  }

Comment: I've updated my code to play a sound at the end of the countdown, tell me if that works for you :)

Comment: Thanks -- I really appreciate the clarity of your answers. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't have jquery.js and you are using $('#countdown')

You don't have any function called cdreset .

Well I wrote a similar code for you :

```js
<script>
var m = setInterval(start, 1000), // init the interval , every 1 sec will call start function
    s = 60;
function start(){
    s = s -1;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = s;
}
function stop(){
    clearInterval(m);
}

</script>
<p id="count">60</p>     
<input type="submit" onclick="stop()" value="stop" />
```

it will count down starting from 60 to -XXX

You should add a condition so as to stop the timer at 0 :)

Comment: Sorry -- didn't see that SO doesn't like <head> tags. Corrected it to show the external scripts.